# DataFrame to Json Array in Spark

Tags: java, arrays, json, apache-spark

I am writing Spark Application in Java which reads the HiveTable and store the output in HDFS as Json Format.

I read the hive table using `HiveContext` and it returns the DataFrame. Below is the code snippet.

```
 SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("App");
 JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
 HiveContext hiveContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc);

DataFrame data1= hiveContext.sql("select * from tableName")
```

Now I want to convert `DataFrame` to `JsonArray`. For Example, data1 data looks like below

```
|  A  |     B     |
-------------------
|  1  | test      |
|  2  | mytest    |
```

I need an output like below

```
[{1:"test"},{2:"mytest"}]
```

I tried using `data1.schema.json()` and it gives me the output like below, not an Array.

```
{1:"test"}
{2:"mytest"}
```

What is the right approach or function to convert the `DataFrame` to `jsonArray` without using any third Party libraries.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`data1.schema.json` will give you a JSON string containing the schema of the dataframe and not the actual data itself. You will get :

```
String = {"type":"struct",
          "fields":
                  [{"name":"A","type":"integer","nullable":false,"metadata":{}},
                  {"name":"B","type":"string","nullable":true,"metadata":{}}]}
```

To convert your dataframe to array of JSON, you need to use `toJSON` method of DataFrame:

```
val df = sc.parallelize(Array( (1, "test"), (2, "mytest") )).toDF("A", "B")
df.show()

+---+------+
|  A|     B|
+---+------+
|  1|  test|
|  2|mytest|
+---+------+

df.toJSON.collect.mkString("[", "," , "]" )
String = [{"A":1,"B":"test"},{"A":2,"B":"mytest"}]
```

Comment: In Java, `mkString` not working.  `toString()` wont get any arguments.

Comment: If you're using Java 8, you can use [StringJoiner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html)

Answer (score 1):

in JAVA you can do it with the following way:

```
String jsonToReturn = df.toJSON().collectAsList().toString();
reutrn jsonToReturn;
```

and `return` it as a `response` if it's a *server-side*.